# something about sendtransform, quaternion and euler

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,you,
I'm a clown boy and the following params puzzled me,can you make a description for me?
My questions are:
first:I don't understand "the translation of the transformtion as a tuple (x, y, z)",It seems that translation is equal to transformtion,they has same means unexpectedly! And what do "msg.x" , "msg.y" and "0" actually mean in robot pose?
Can i comprehend like this:msg.x and msg.y are Coordinate value where 0 means z=0?

second:param rotation: the rotation of the transformation as a tuple (x, y, z, w),what does (0, 0, msg.theta) mean in robot pose?And what are the relations between rotation and translation?

```
sendTransform((msg.x,msg.y,0),
                        tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, msg.theta),
                        rospy.Time.now(),
                        turtlename,
                        "world")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215900/something-about-sendtransform,-quaternion-and-euler/) by [unicornair](https://answers.ros.org/users/23386/unicornair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't, but should've provided a link to the source of the code you show. I believe it came from the [Writing a tf broadcaster in Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29).

*Translation*, in this context, refers to linear movement through space. *Transformation* refers to the conversion of a position in 3d space (location and orientation) between frames of reference. A *transform* in ROS represents the position of an object in 3d space at a specific time between two specific frames of reference.

In the case you cite, a fixed elevation (*z* location coordinate) is given, which happens to be 0. Also, only the *theta* value (i.e., *yaw*, rotation around the Z axis) of the Euler orientation changes -- the *pitch* and *roll* (rotation around the Y and X axes, respectively) are fixed at 0.

Putting that all together, as the turtle moves in its own frame of reference (i.e., *turtlename*), its *(x,y)* location and *theta* orientation changes (in 2d space on the plane with *z=0*) relative to the *world* frame of reference. The `sendTransform` method enters that information into ROS's TF system with an assigned timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unicornair](https://answers.ros.org/users/23386/unicornair/) on 2015-08-18**:
Thanks for your detail answer,It helps me out